# Accessing inner modules defining api parameters in ng-swagger-gen

Tags: angular, typescript

I am relatively new to angular and type script. I am designing a new spring/angular framework for use at my company and I'm utilizing the ng-swagger-gen project to generate an angular client from the spring controllers.

My problem is that when I define more than one parameter for a controller, ng-swagger-gen creates an interface to contain them, which I cannot figure out how to import from the consuming component.

Below is the generated API

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BaseService as __BaseService } from '../base-service';
import { ApiConfiguration as __Configuration } from '../api-configuration';
import { StrictHttpResponse as __StrictHttpResponse } from '../strict-http-response';
import { Observable as __Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map as __map, filter as __filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { VehicleBean } from '../models/vehicle-bean';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
class ApiService extends __BaseService {
  static readonly helloPath = '/hello/sayhi';
  static readonly findVehiclePath = '/vehicle/find';
  static readonly listVehiclesPath = '/vehicle/list';

  constructor(
    config: __Configuration,
    http: HttpClient
  ) {
    super(config, http);
  }

  /**
   * @param toWhom undefined
   * @return successful operation
   */
  helloResponse(toWhom: string): __Observable<__StrictHttpResponse<string>> {
    let __params = this.newParams();
    let __headers = new HttpHeaders();
    let __body: any = null;
    if (toWhom != null) __params = __params.set('toWhom', toWhom.toString());
    let req = new HttpRequest<any>(
      'POST',
      this.rootUrl + `/hello/sayhi`,
      __body,
      {
        headers: __headers,
        params: __params,
        responseType: 'text'
      });

    return this.http.request<any>(req).pipe(
      __filter(_r => _r instanceof HttpResponse),
      __map((_r) => {
        return _r as __StrictHttpResponse<string>;
      })
    );
  }
  /**
   * @param toWhom undefined
   * @return successful operation
   */
  hello(toWhom: string): __Observable<string> {
    return this.helloResponse(toWhom).pipe(
      __map(_r => _r.body as string)
    );
  }

  /**
   * @return successful operation
   */
  findVehicleResponse(): __Observable<__StrictHttpResponse<VehicleBean>> {
    let __params = this.newParams();
    let __headers = new HttpHeaders();
    let __body: any = null;
    let req = new HttpRequest<any>(
      'GET',
      this.rootUrl + `/vehicle/find`,
      __body,
      {
        headers: __headers,
        params: __params,
        responseType: 'json'
      });

    return this.http.request<any>(req).pipe(
      __filter(_r => _r instanceof HttpResponse),
      __map((_r) => {
        return _r as __StrictHttpResponse<VehicleBean>;
      })
    );
  }
  /**
   * @return successful operation
   */
  findVehicle(): __Observable<VehicleBean> {
    return this.findVehicleResponse().pipe(
      __map(_r => _r.body as VehicleBean)
    );
  }

  /**
   * @param params The `ApiService.ListVehiclesParams` containing the following parameters:
   *
   * - `offset`:
   *
   * - `howMany`:
   *
   * @return successful operation
   */
  listVehiclesResponse(params: ApiService.ListVehiclesParams): __Observable<__StrictHttpResponse<Array<VehicleBean>>> {
    let __params = this.newParams();
    let __headers = new HttpHeaders();
    let __body: any = null;
    if (params.offset != null) __params = __params.set('offset', params.offset.toString());
    if (params.howMany != null) __params = __params.set('howMany', params.howMany.toString());
    let req = new HttpRequest<any>(
      'GET',
      this.rootUrl + `/vehicle/list`,
      __body,
      {
        headers: __headers,
        params: __params,
        responseType: 'json'
      });

    return this.http.request<any>(req).pipe(
      __filter(_r => _r instanceof HttpResponse),
      __map((_r) => {
        return _r as __StrictHttpResponse<Array<VehicleBean>>;
      })
    );
  }
  /**
   * @param params The `ApiService.ListVehiclesParams` containing the following parameters:
   *
   * - `offset`:
   *
   * - `howMany`:
   *
   * @return successful operation
   */
  listVehicles(params: ApiService.ListVehiclesParams): __Observable<Array<VehicleBean>> {
    return this.listVehiclesResponse(params).pipe(
      __map(_r => _r.body as Array<VehicleBean>)
    );
  }
}

module ApiService {

  /**
   * Parameters for listVehicles
   */
  export interface ListVehiclesParams {
    offset: number;
    howMany: number;
  }
}

export { ApiService }
```

Which I've packaged into a library called poc-client-v2. I can import and inject the ApiService itself like so.

```
import {ApiService} from 'poc-client-v2';
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms';
import {debounceTime} from 'rxjs/operators'; 
import {VehicleBean} from  'poc-client-v2/api/models/vehicle-bean';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-vehicle-list-example',
  templateUrl: './vehicle-list-example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./vehicle-list-example.component.css']
})


export class VehicleListExampleComponent implements OnInit {


  filterGroup: FormGroup;
  vehicles : VehicleBean[];

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private apiService: ApiService) {
    this.filterGroup = this.createFormGroup();

  }

  ngOnInit() {
     console.log('user list init: ');

    this.filterGroup.get('criteria').valueChanges.pipe( debounceTime(1000) ).subscribe(
      field=> { 
        console.log('criteria changed: ' + field);
       // Can't instantiate a new ListVehiclesParams here without the proper import
       // this.apiService.listVehicles(new ListVehiclesParams(0,20)).subscribe(data => {this.vehicles=data;})
      } 
    );
  }

   createFormGroup() {
    return new FormGroup({
      criteria: new FormControl('')
    });
  }
}
```

but I cannot figure out how to import the ListVehiclesParams interface within the ApiService module defined at the bottom of the generated ApiService so I can invoke the listVehicles method. Can someone show me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

the answer was not to import it at all.. but to just implement a json formatted object with the correct parameter names.

`this.apiService.listVehicles({offset:10,howMany:10}).subscribe(data => {this.vehicles=data;})`

Comment: this is a fine solution, but I've submitted an answer that should hopefully explain the situation a bit more thoroughly

Answer (score 0):

To address the primary question, in order to access `ListVehiclesParams`, you should be able to use `ApiService.ListVehiclesParams`.

However, if you did that, you would have noticed an error due to the fact that you can't instantiate an interface this way in typescript. `new ListVehiclesParams(0,20)` is the syntax used for classes, but you instantiate interfaces as plain objects (which is what you ended up doing in your answer), like:

```js
const params: ApiService.ListVehicleParams = {
   offset: 10,
   howMany: 10,
};
this.apiService.listVehicles(params).subscribe(data => {this.vehicles=data;})
```

You can find more information about this on [Typescript's page on interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html)

**However**, with all of that said, one of the greatest strengths of typescript is its ability to infer types, and enforce safety on those inferred types. In many cases, leaving off the type and just creating an instance of the interface inline is the most concise and readable solution, so I think the way you've done this is great. In your solution that used `this.apiService.listVehicles({offset: 10, howMany: 10})`, behind the scenes, typescript knows exactly what type is supposed to be passed to that method. Because of that, it'll throw an error if you pass something that doesn't meet the interface definition, e.g. a typo like `{ofset: 10, howmany: 10}`.